# Linux kernel: Where do the process page tables reside?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

Being used only by the kernel, they should only lie in the addresses above PAGE_OFFSET. But I was reading [this](http://linux-mm.org/VirtualMemory) page and at the end of it (in the IRC convo) I read the following lines which really confused me:

```
 saxm> riel:  so where do page tables reside? Surely not below PAGE_OFFSET? Somewhere above PAGE_OFFSET+896mb then?

riel> they could reside anywhere

saxm> anywhere from 0->4gb (on x86 with no pae)?

riel> saxm: yeah
```

I mean, why would they lie below PAGE_OFFSET? Wouldn't user space processes be able to access them if that is the case?

Answer (score 5):

I think what riel was trying to say is that they can reside (almost) anywhere in *physical* memory--there's not a fixed mapping.

Page tables are mapped in the kernel virtual address space (i.e. above PAGE_OFFSET), and are invisible to user space (which, like you point out, makes sense because we wouldn't want users clobbering their own page tables).

Take a look at this related post:
[Does Linux use self-map for page directory and page tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272408/does-linux-use-self-map-for-page-directory-and-page-tables)