# How different in management page table entries (PTE) in kernel space and user space?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory, mmu, page-tables

In Linux OS, after enable the page table, kernel will only map PTEs belong to kernel space once and never remap them again ? This action is opposite with PTEs in the user space which needs to remap every time process switching happening ?

So, I want know the difference in management of PTEs in kernel and user space.

This question is a extended part from the question at:
[Page table in Linux kernel space during boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688540/page-table-in-linux-kernel-space)

Answer (score 3):

Each process has its own page tables (although the parts that describe the kernel's address space are the same and are shared.)

On a process switch, the CPU is told the address of the new table (this is a single pointer which is written to the CR3 register on x86 CPUs).

Answer (score 0):

> So, I want know the difference in management of PTEs in kernel and user space.

See these related questions,

- [Does Linux use self map for page tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272408/does-linux-use-self-map-for-page-directory-and-page-tables)
- [Linux Virtual memory](http://linux-mm.org/VirtualMemory)
- [Kernel developer on memory management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html)
- [Position independent code and shared libraries](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/)

There are many optimizations to this,

Each task has a different **PGD**, but **PTE** values maybe shared between processes, so large chunks of memory can be mapped the same for each process; only the top-level directory (CR3 on x86, TTB on ARM) is updated.

Also, many CPUs have a TLB and cache.  These need to be maintained with the memory mapping.  Some caches are VIVT, VIPT and PIPT.  The first two have to have some cache flushing **iff** the PGD and/or PTE change.  Often a CPU will support a process, thread or domain id.  The OS only needs to switch this register during a context switch.  The hardware cache and TLB entries must contains tags with the process, thread, or domain id.  This is an implementation detail for each architecture.

So it is possible that TLB flushes could be needed when a top level page registers changes.  The CPU could flush the entire TLB when this happens.  However, this would be a disadvantage to pages that remain mapped.

Also, sub-sections of memory can be the same.  A loader or other library can use `mmap` to create code that is similar between processes.  This common code may not need to be swapped at the page table level, depending on architecture, loader and Linux version.  It could of course have a virtual alias and then it needs to be swapped.

And the final point to the answer; **kernel pages are always mapped**.  Only a non-preemptive OS could not map the kernel, but that would make little sense as every process wants to call the kernel.  I guess the micro-kernel paradigm allows for device drivers to *unload* when they are not in use.  Linux uses module loading to handle this.